# Connection is forcibly closed by remote host (SSL)

Tags: c#, google-sheets, google-api, google-drive-api

I am currently investigating an issue I get on a server at a remote location. When I run a service on that specific server am I getting an error. The service purpose is to upload files from computer then into a specific folder on a shared drive in Google Drive. All information are  located in the settings of the service. The service is written in C# .Net and uses the namespace Google.Apis.Requests.

The error is displayed bellow:

```
The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
```

The inner exception is:

```
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacketAsync(Stream transport, AsyncProtocolRequest request)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ThrowIfExceptional()
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsClientAsync>b__65_1(IAsyncResult iar)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

The above error is happening when I execute my request to the Google.Apis.Drive.v3 API.

I have a boolean looking if I have a connection. I am having a connection before executing my request.

1. I tried remaking a virtual machine environment where I installed the exact same software + settings. On there did it work fine.
2. I tried turning off the firewall to see if it caused anything. The error were still the same on the server.
3. I can access the internet and can log into Google Drive on a browser from the server.

EDIT:

The full exception being written is the following:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacketAsync(Stream transport, AsyncProtocolRequest request)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ThrowIfExceptional()
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsClientAsync>b__65_1(IAsyncResult iar)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Google.Apis.Http.ConfigurableMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Requests.TokenRequestExtenstions.ExecuteAsync(TokenRequest request, HttpClient httpClient, String tokenServerUrl, CancellationToken taskCancellationToken, IClock clock, ILogger logger)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken taskCancellationToken)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.TokenRefreshManager.RefreshTokenAsync()
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.TokenRefreshManager.ResultWithUnwrappedExceptions[T](Task`1 task)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.TokenRefreshManager.<>c.<GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync>b__10_0(Task`1 task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__274_0(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.TokenRefreshManager.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync(String authUri, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceCredential.GetAccessTokenWithHeadersForRequestAsync(String authUri, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceCredential.InterceptAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Google.Apis.Http.ConfigurableMessageHandler.CredentialInterceptAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Google.Apis.Http.ConfigurableMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.ExecuteUnparsedAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.Execute()
   at Integration.ReportService.Infrastructure.Helpers.GoogleDriveHelper.GetSharedDrives(Int32 pageSize) in E:\github\ws\Integration.ReportService\Integration.ReportService\src\Integration.ReportService\Integration.ReportService\Infrastructure\Helpers\GoogleDriveHelper.cs:line 128
```

Comment: Which .NET Framework version are you using? On which OS? All clouds services require at least TLS 1.2 since 2016-ish. All *supported* versions of Windows and .NET (4.6.2 and later) use this by default. In older Windows versions you had to patch your OS to enable TLS 1.2. Old (and now unsupported) .NET Framework versions didn't use TLS 1.2 automatically either

Comment: The error "forcibly closed by the remote host" usually occurs when you try to make more than one  TCP connection with the same source IP, destination IP, and Port number.  HTTP uses TCP as the transport layer.  So your HTTP library is making connection using TCP methods.  Are you using LocalHost or 127.0.0.1 as the IP?  Instead try the machine name or the IP of the server.

Comment: BTW there are a *lot* of similar questions for this exact error message. The real solution is to use a supported .NET version on a supported Windows version and let them automatically pick the best algorithm. Anything else, like hard-coding the TLS version is really just a hack that *prevents* the use of eg TLS 1.3 on newer machines. And some of the bad answers actually re-enable weak algorithms like SSL v3 for no good reason, exposing you to hack attacks.

Comment: @jdweng the code is trying to connect to Google Drive and the error mentions SSL.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : I know.  It look like OP is using OpenSSL and details of error message indicates "forcibly closed by the remote host" which usually isn't a TLS failure.

Comment: @jdweng how did you determine it's OpenSSL? That would mean it's not Windows and thus not .NET Framework

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : You are correct.  It is a SSLStream which still is using TCP for the connection and not an HTTP library.

Comment: @jdweng There are a bunch of different reasons you get that message (it comes via a `RST` packet), but this one is clearly because the SSL/TLS tunnel is not coming up, and is quite standard when one side decides it can't negotiate the tunnel and shuts down.

Comment: Googling for the error and `EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore` returns several results where the TLS version was obsolete. The full stack trace was a lot longer too, pointing to the actual call that caused the error. The question's stack trace is incomplete

Comment: @Smuller97 please post the entire *full* exception text returned by `Exception.ToString()`, not just the inner exception. If the remote machine runs a supported Windows version the best option would be to upgrade .NET Framework to at least 4.6.2, the oldest supported version. If the Windows version is unsupported, you'll have to patch the OS. The specifics depend on the Windows version. In some cases you'd only need to change a setting in Registry

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Network Tracing in the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/network-tracing)

Comment: @Charlieface : All we know is the secure connection was not established.  We cannot tell if the TCP connection completed or if the failure occurred when TLS was being negotiated.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The  OS is a Windows Server 2022. The .NET that is running is ASP.NET Core 3.1.32 - Shared framework x64

Comment: Post the *entire* exception, not just the inner one. BTW .NET Core 3.1 reached End-of-Life last year. The oldest supported .NET Core runtime is .NET 6. This may or may *not* be relevant. .NET Core 3.1 worked fine with TLS 1.2 but TLS 1.3 on Windows didn't exist back then. .NET Core 3 [only allowed TLS 1.3 on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#tls-13--openssl-111-on-linux)

Comment: If this is a .NET Core 3.1 bug, there's no fix precisely because 3.1 is past End-Of-Life. You should change the application's target version to 6. If you can't install the .NET 6 runtime on the remote machine, publish a self-contained application. That will include all the necessary runtime files in the application itself. The size will be bigger but you won't have to install the runtime

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I just made an edit to the post and pasted the full exception. I just don't get why it does not work on 1 server, when it works on 25 others with the same setup of installed software

Comment: If only one server is failing a few things could be happening 1) A different version of Core is installed on server.  2) A Certificate is missing on the server. 3) A route is missing from server to the shared folder.  To check access to the shared folder I would use a File Explorer on the server and see if you can read/write to the shared upload folder manually.